# jquery multiple binds

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding

fellow coders, assuming that I have a button with a click handler like so:

```
$("#save-item-btn").click(function() { saveItemDialogData(true); });
```

if the same code is executed again, would jquery realize that, clear the previous bind and reapply it or would it consume resources or cause unnecessary side effects?

thanks

Comment: I _believe_ it will add it to the "bind queue", not re-assign it (Especially since it's not a named function).

Comment: What do you mean by "if the same code is executed again"? Executed by what, the click event? Do you mean if the user clicks twice?

Comment: as per my knowledge, it applies the last binding. It won't create any side effects. it is better if more knowledgeable person confirms it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call click(), it will bind the function you give it to that handler -- it can't tell that the function is the same. If you want to be sure that there are no prior click handlers on your button, first call unbind('click') on it and then attach your click handlers.

Note that assigning to the onclick property directly *will* replace the existing handler with whatever you assign to it; allowing multiple functions to be bound to the same event is a jQuery feature.

Comment: this can remove useful handler assigned in different place

Comment: True, but I did qualify that statement by saying that you'd call it to be sure that there were no prior click handlers, not just the one you'd registered before.

Answer (score 4):

If the function is bound twice, the function will be added twice, and execute twice on every click event.

If you need to make sure that you're not re-binding the function 100 times, unbind the function before re-binding:

```
$("#save-item-btn").unbind('click', doSave).click(doSave);

function doSave()
{
  saveItemDialogData(true);
}
```

Comment: this can remove useful handler assigned in different place

Comment: @vittore, nope, you'll notice i used a named function. It will *only* remove the specified handler from the queue. Any other useful click handlers will remain attached.

Answer (score 3):

If this code will be executed again the new function will be added to click queue. As @Faisal noticed you can call `unbind` in order to remove handler but it could remove usefull handlers from other parts of app, so you probably should use handler namespaces like this:

```
$(selector).unbind('click.mynamespace');
$(selector).bind('click.mynamespace', myhandler);
```

this way you will only replace your own handler

Comment: +1 for mentioning handler namespaces -- I neglected that in my answer. :) @zzzzBov's suggestion of passing the handler to unbind() works as well, but it doesn't allow the function to be anonymous.

Comment: many thanks guys for the responses and sorry for being late to respond. zzzzBov, Faisal, patrick and vitore you were all right. I was getting confused hence the question because i did not experience the expected behavior (i.e multiple calls to the handler) but then i realized the button in question is part of a DOM structure i'm loading dynamically and then destroying later. So in essence the scenario I described was not even taking place :) Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2):

It will attach a second click event handler and leave the original handler. In that case you are specifically using an anonymous function, jQuery couldn't possibly know if a similar function is already attached or not to the element.

You can use unbind to detach previous handlers. It's preferable to use Namespaced events as described here: http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events.